# can I define the activemq admin console url?

Tags: port, activemq-classic

Activemq's admin console, as standard, points to 0.0.0.0:8161.

I know I can change the port from 8161 in the jetty.xml config file.

Is it possible to change the URL from 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was pretty obvious. In jetty.xml:

```
<bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
    <property name="port" value="8161" />
    <property name="host" value="HOSTNAME" />
</bean>
```